# Почему jquery validation не обрабатывает ввод?

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-validation

Простая форма с одним полем и кнопкой, нужно проверить что поле заполнено и что его длинна не менее 5 символов, при помощи `jquery validation`, но почему-то не работает. Форма всегда отправляется вне зависимости есть в ней что-то или нет.

`index.html`

```
<head>
    <title>Form</title>

    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="validation.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="p-x-1 p-y-3">
        <form id="form" class="card card-block m-x-auto bg-faded form-width" method="POST" action="go" name="validation">
            <legend class="m-b-1 text-xs-center">Enter data</legend>

            <div class="form-group input-group">
                <span class="has-float-label">
                <input class="form-control" name="name" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name"/>
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                </span>
            </div>

            <div class="text-xs-center">
                <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary" type="submit">Edit</button>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

И проверка этого поля:

```
$(function() {
  $("form[name='validation']").validate({

    rules: {
      name: "required",
      minlength: 5
    },

    // Error message.
    messages: {
      name: "Error"
    },

    submitHandler: function(form) {
      form.submit();
    }
  });
});
```

Возможно проблема в том что я не правильно подключил `jquery validation` или в коде ошибка?

Папка `jquery-validation` лежит в той же директории что и `index.html`.

Помогите пожалуйста исправить. Спасибо.

Comment: Вы не забыли подключить библиотеку jQuery `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @Shnur подключил но не помогло.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще в мануалах так написано.

```
$("form[name='validation']").validate({
   rules: {
      name: {
         required: true,
         minlength: 5
      }
   },
...
```

Comment: к сожалению не помогло((